# Add Input Elements in Canvas HTML5

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to create a draggable input text box in Canvas, but Canvas doesn't seem to be allowing creation of any input element. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include HTML elements in Canvas. HTML5 Canvas is a surface reserved for drawing. You are drawing it from Javascipt code after obtaining Graphics Context.

Maybe you can use just CSS positioning to handle  moving around the HTML. It can be done with/without Canvas.